# Map an array by value

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects, which I want to sum by condition.

```
[{amount:100, prefix:'a'},{amount:50, prefix:'b'},{amount:70, prefix:'a'},{amount:100, prefix:'b'}]
```

Is there is a way to map the values, such as I will have two sums, one is 170, of prefix 'a', and one of 150 of prefix 'b'?

Comment: can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: @Kektuto Assuming I have an array, I'd like to sum it, by the value of each prefix. The sum of all amounts with prefix 'a' are 170, 100+70 , and the sum of all amounts with prefix 'b' are 150, as there are two objects with the prefix 'b', one has amount of 100, and the other has amount of 50

Comment: @user3150947 what output do you expect?

Comment: {'a' : 170, 'b': 150}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const result = [{amount:100, prefix:'a'},{amount:50, prefix:'b'},{amount:70, prefix:'a'},{amount:100, prefix:'b'}].reduce(
  (acc, {amount, prefix}) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [prefix]: acc[prefix] + amount
    }
   
  }, {a: 0, b: 0}
);


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function compute_sums(acc, curr) {
    if (acc[curr['prefix']]) {
        acc[curr['prefix']] += curr['amount']
    } else {
       acc[curr['prefix']] = curr['amount']
   }
   return acc;
}
const arr = [{amount:100, prefix:'c'}, {amount:100, prefix:'a'},{amount:50, prefix:'b'},{amount:70, prefix:'a'},{amount:100, prefix:'b'}];
const answer = arr.reduce(compute_sums, {});
console.log(answer);
```

Similar answer to Ali, but mine will compute the sums for any prefix, not just a and b.